# Do you know the word ROUTABILITY?

Tags: word-usage

Is the word "routability" appropriate in the context of electrical engineering? I want to express whether the electrical routes between components can be routed or not.

Comment: This question surely belongs on a forum about electrical engineering, because it is about usage in that technical field - not about general English language usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a forum about electrical engineering.

Comment: It's legitimate to "abilify" most verbs.  The hard part is whether the suffix should be "-able" or "-ible".

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=%22routability%22

Comment: @TrevorD Please see the link above.

Comment: @ Hot Licks: So he is asking for the abilifibility of the word "route". (I suppose that we can abilify the word "abilify" ?) ;-)

Comment: @Kris I fail to see the relevance of a Google search on "routability".  Op is asking about the usage of terminology in electrical engineering.  That is surely a question for a forum about electrical engineering - not one about the English Language.

Comment: @TrevorD Too early to be judgmental for us. Let's see.

Comment: I only object to the lack of background research effort on the part of the OP.